# IIS application with virtual directories running code in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, iis, virtual-directory

If I have an ASP.NET application in IIS with virtual directories, can aspx pages in the virtual directories access DLLs within that application as well?

```
WEBSITE  
 -App___Data  
 -App_Themes  
 -Bin  
   -MyDLL.dll  
 -Images  
 -MyVirtualDir  
   -MyAspPageThatNeedsToAccessMyDll.aspx
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, assuming that all the folders are running under the same application.  If the "MyVirtualDir" was its own application, then I don't think it'll work.

Comment: Yes, I just realized that my DLL wasn't built so I was seeing the methods in intellisense but would error our when I tried to run it.